# Highlighting parts of a web document

Tags: html, css, web

The following is how code looks on stack overflow:

```
float foo(int a, float b, char c){
    float d = a*b;
    printf("%c", c);
    return d;
}
```

I wish to highlight code in a similar manner. How does one achieve this?

Comment: Where is the HTML and CSS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exact library Stackoverflow is using to highlight their code snippets, but [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/usage/) is a widely used one to achieve this.